# Demonstrate using determinant properties that the determinant of $A$ is equal to $2abc(a+b+c)^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How can I show using properties of determinants that:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & a^2 & a^2 \\
b^2 & (c+a)^2 & b^2 \\
c^2 & c^2 & (a+b)^2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 2abc(a+b+c)^3$$

Comment: Starting with Sarrus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus ??

Comment: Sorry i already know the Sarrus law. The matter is to get the result using the properties of determinants like: $det(B)=-det(A)$ if $B$ is $A$ with two columns interchanged. Or $det(B)=Kdet(A)$ IF $B$ is $A$ with a column multiplied by $K$, there are some few known importants properties of determinantes of linear algebra. It is no requested to use some weird properties.

Comment: @Amzoti I have already use Sarrus Law, but it get to much complicated, in this excersise is just requested to avoid using that law, and get the result in a simpler way using de correct properties of determinants.

Comment: @MattAllegro I just wrote you something after your comment but I forgot to call you, maybe the next comment I did, could help you to indicate a better way to proceed.

Comment: @Amzoti Cofactors and Sarrus, are not what I refer to be Determinant properties. Those are what I need to use. I gues Im in the same hole.

Comment: See also [How to solve this determinant](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1889822). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%242abc(a%2Bb%2Bc)%5E3%24%2C%20determinant&p=1)

Comment: @MartinSleziak In your link the matrix do not have de factor a^2, in my matrix the factor a^2 is in the first , so I it is not the same excersise.

Answer (score 3):

the value of the determinant is evidently a homogeneous symmetric polynomial D(a,b,c) of degree six.

it is easy to see that it vanishes if $a=0$, $b=0$ or $c=0$.

and if $a+b+c=0$ then $(b+c)^2=a^2$  etc. , so again the determinant vanishes.

hence for suitably chosen $\lambda$ and $\mu$
$$
D(a,b,c) = abc(a+b+c)\left(\lambda (a^2+b^2+c^2) + \mu(ab+bc+ca) \right)
$$
we may easily compute $D(1,1,1)=54$, hence
$$
\lambda+\mu = 6
$$
likewise $D(2,1,1) = 256$, giving:
$$
6\lambda +5 \mu = 32
$$thus  $\lambda=2$ and $\mu=4$, so
$$
\lambda (a^2+b^2+c^2) + \mu(ab+bc+ca) = 2(a+b+c)^2
$$
and, finally:
$$
D(a,b,c) = 2abc(a+b+c)^3
$$

Comment: This needs solved like this \begin{equation}
\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\
     x & y & z \\
    x^2  &    y^2     &  z^2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
     x & y-x & z-x \\
    x^2  &    y^2-x^2     &  z^2-x^2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}y-x & z-x \\
     y^2-x^2 & z^2-x^2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}y-x & z-x \\
     (y-x)(y+x) & (z-x)(z+x) \\
 \end{pmatrix}=(y-x)(z-x)\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
     y+x & z+x \\
 \end{pmatrix} = (y-x)(z-x)\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
     y+x & z-y \\
 \end{pmatrix}=(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)
\end{equation}

Comment: This past comment reflects how the excercise requires to be  @DavidHolden solved, so your answer is very comprehensible, but this excercise needs to be solved by known procedures. Like the past I have posted, but I have really enjoid your answer.

Comment: How can you write $D(a,b,c) = abc(a+b+c)\left[\lambda (a^2+b^2+c^2) + \mu(ab+bc+ca) \right]$  after you obtained $abc(a+b+c)$ as factor ?

Comment: that is the form is must take if it is a homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree six divisible by $abc(a+b+c)$.