# Solve the determinant.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove that the following determinant is equal to $$2abc(a+b+c)^3$$

Using row column operations.

$$
\det        \begin{pmatrix}
        (b+c)^2 & a^2 & a^2 \\
        b^2 & (c+a)^2 & b^2 \\
        c^2 & c^2 & (a+b)^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
I tried using various row and column operations but without any success.

Comment: At least present what the determinant calculation you have made.

Comment: I tried using various row and column operations but without any success

Comment: Why do you need to use row / column operations? Can't you just calculate the determinant directly from the definition?

Comment: If we calculate it directly the problem becomes quite lengthy and complex @Arthur

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954623/demonstrate-using-determinant-properties-that-the-determinant-of-matrix-a-is-e
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889822/how-to-solve-this-determinanat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & a^2 &a^2\\
b^2 & (c+a)^2 & b^2\\
c^2&c^2&(a+b)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c)^2-a^2 & 0 & a^2\\
0 & (c+a)^2-b^2 & b^2\\
c^2-(a+b)^2 & c^2-(a+b)^2 & (a+b)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
By $C_1-C_3$, $C_2-C_3$

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c+a)(b+c-a) & 0 & a^2\\
0 & (c+a+b)(c+a-b) & b^2\\
(c+a+b)(c-a-b) & (c+a+b)(c-a-b) & (a+b)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$(a+b+c)^2\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c-a) & 0 & a^2\\
0 & (c+a-b) & b^2\\
(c-a-b) & (c-a-b) & (a+b)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
By Taking Common $(a+b+c)$ from each $C_1$ and $C_2$

$$(a+b+c)^2\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c-a) & 0 & a^2\\
0 & (c+a-b) & b^2\\
-2b & -2a & 2ab
\end{pmatrix}$$
By $R_3-(R_1+R_2)$

$$(a+b+c)^2\det \begin{pmatrix}
(b+c-a) & 0 & a^2\\
0 & (c+a-b) & b(c+a)\\
(c-a-b) & (c-a-b) & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
By $C_3+bC_2$

Now By expanding determinant we get

$$=2abc(a+b+c)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
        (b+c)^2 & a^2 & a^2 \\
        b^2 & (c+a)^2 & b^2 \\
        c^2 & c^2 & (a+b)^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ Replace $C_1$ by$ C_1−C_2$ and $ C_2$ by $C_2−C_3$, we have,

$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}
        (b+c)^2-a^2 & 0 & a^2 \\
        b^2-(c+a)^2 & (c+a)^2-b^2 & b^2 \\
       0 & c^2-(a+b)^2 & (a+b)^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$$(a+b+c)^2\det \begin{pmatrix}
        b+c-a & 0 & a^2 \\
        b-c-a & c+a-b & b^2 \\
        0 & c-a-b & (a+b)^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: We don't usually post multiple answers to the same question unless they are different in some essential way. I'm not sure that we have a definite rule but I have misgivings about posting first a hint and then following up on it in a different post. Why did you not edit the hint?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Replace $C_1$ by $C_1-C_2$ and $C_2$ by $C_2-C_3$

Comment: Thanks man. And then what to do ?