# How to extract $(x+y+z)$ or $xyz$ from the determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove
$$\color{blue}{
\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
(y+z)^2&xy&zx\\
xy&(x+z)^2&yz\\
xz&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{vmatrix}=2xyz(x+y+z)^3}
$$
using elementary operations and the properties of the determinants without expanding.

**My Attempt**
$$
\Delta\stackrel{C_1\rightarrow C_1+C_2+C_3}{=}\begin{vmatrix}
xy+y^2+yz+zx+yz+z^2&xy&zx\\
x^2+xy+xz+xz+yz+z^2&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x^2+xy+xz+xy+y^2+yz&yz&(x+y)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
=\begin{vmatrix}
y(x+y+z)+z(x+y+z)&xy&zx\\
x(x+y+z)+z(x+y+z)&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x(x+y+z)+y(x+y+z)&yz&(x+y)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
=(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}
y+z&xy&zx\\
x+z&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x+y&yz&(x+y)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
\stackrel{R_1\rightarrow R_1+R_2+R_3}{=} \\(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}
2(x+y+z)&x^2+xy+xz+xz+yz+z^2&x^2+xy+zx+xy+y^2+yz\\
x+z&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x+y&yz&(x+y)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
=(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
2&x+z&x+y\\
x+z&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x+y&yz&(x+y)^2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
=2(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{x+z}{2}&\frac{x+y}{2}\\
x+z&(x+z)^2&yz\\
x+y&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{vmatrix}
\stackrel{R_2\rightarrow R_2-(x+z)R_1|R_2\rightarrow R_3-(x+y)R_1}{=}
2(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{x+z}{2}&\frac{x+y}{2}\\
0&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}\\
0&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}&\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
$$
How do I extract $x+y+z$ or $xyz$ from the determinant to find the solution ?

**Note:** In a similar problem [How to solve this determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889822/how-to-solve-this-determinant) there seems to be solutions talking about factor theorem and polynomials. I am basically looking for extracting the terms $(x+y+z)$ or $xyz$ from the given determinant to solve it only using the basic properties of determinants.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the last determinant by hand? It's not so difficult and it yields $x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2=xyz(x+y+z)$.

Comment: @Andrei thnx for commenting. To be frank i did not. But i was wondering is it possible to extract $x+y+z$ or $xyz$ which could make it simpler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
(y+z)^2&xy&zx\\
xy&(x+z)^2&yz\\
xz&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{vmatrix}=xyz\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{(y+z)^2}{x}&x&x\\
y&\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&y\\
z&z&\frac{(x+y)^2}{z}
\end{vmatrix}=
xyz\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{(y+z)^2}{x}-x&x&0\\
y-\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&y-\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}\\
0&z&\frac{(x+y)^2}{z}-z
\end{vmatrix}=
xyz\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{(y+z)^2-x^2}{x}&x&0\\
\frac{y^2-(x+z)^2}{y}&\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&\frac{y^2-(x+z)^2}{y}\\
0&z&\frac{(x+y)^2}{z}
\end{vmatrix}=
xyz\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{[(y+z)-x][(y+z)+x]}{x}&x&0\\
\frac{[y-(x+z)][y+(x+z)]}{y}&\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&\frac{[y-(x+z)][y+(x+z)]}{y}\\
0&z&\frac{[(x+y)-z][(x+y)+z]}{z}
\end{vmatrix}=
xyz(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{[(y+z)-x]}{x}&x&0\\
\frac{[y-(x+z)]}{y}&\frac{(x+z)^2}{y}&\frac{[y-(x+z)]}{y}\\
0&z&\frac{[(x+y)-z]}{z}
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
{[(y+z)-x]}&x^2&0\\
{[y-(x+z)]}&{(x+z)^2}&{[y-(x+z)]}\\
0&z^2&{[(x+y)-z]}
\end{vmatrix}
=(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
{[(y+z)-x]}&x^2&0\\
{[y-(x+z)]}&{(x+z)^2}&{[y-(x+z)]}\\
0&z^2&{[(x+y)-z]}
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
{[(y+z)-x]}&x^2&0\\
-2z&2xz&-2x\\
0&z^2&{[(x+y)-z]}
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)^2\begin{vmatrix}
{(y+z)}&x^2&\frac{x^2}{z}\\
0&2xz&0\\
\frac{z^2}{x}&z^2&{(x+y)}
\end{vmatrix}\\
=(x+y+z)^2.2xz.\Big[(x+y)(y+z)-\frac{x^2.z^2}{xz}\Big]\\
=(x+y+z)^2(2xz)(xy+xz+y^2+xz-xz)\\
=(x+y+z)^2(2xz)(xy+y^2+xz)\\=(x+y+z)^2.2xz.y(x+y+z)=2xyz(x+y+z)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

The determinant must be a polynomial in $x,y,z$ of degree $6$.

If you set $x=0$,

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
(y+z)^2&0&0\\
0&z^2&yz\\
0&yz&y^2
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$

so that $x$ is a factor. And by symmetry, $xyz$ as well.

Then with $x=-y-z$,
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
(y+z)^2&xy&zx\\
xy&y^2&yz\\
xz&yz&z^2
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$ (the bottom six minors are zero), and $x+y+z$ is a factor.

To reach the sixth degree, we are missing two other linear factors. But by symmetry, they cannot be other than $x+y+z$ both (two factors alone cannot sustain a permutation of the variables).

Remains to find the global factor, for example from

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
4&1&1\\
1&4&1\\
1&1&4
\end{vmatrix}=\lambda\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot(1+1+1)^3.$$

Comment: How do u reach the conclusion that the last remaining factor is in the form $\lambda(a+b+c)^2$ ?

Comment: i think i understand how you extracted $xyz$ and $(x+y+z)$. Then you are saying "But by symmetry, they cannot be other than x+y+z both" that i don't understand wht u mean by symmetry. And how do you know there is a "global factor" in the solution ?

Comment: @ss1729: because we found all roots, so that the expression is factored to an unknown constant factor.

Comment: Thanx. But what about the symmetry you are talking about by which you extracted $(x+y+z)^2$. Putting $x,y,z=0$ and $x+y+z=0$ makes determinant zero, thus you obtained $xyz$ and $x+y+z$ right ?. But how do i try to find other factors and obtain a symmetric expression as you said ?

Comment: do u mean: $\Delta=p(x,y,z)$, polynomial in x, y, z of degree 6. $x=0\implies \Delta=p(0,y,z)=0$, $y=0\implies \Delta=p(x,0,z)=0$, $z=0\implies \Delta=p(x,y,0)=0$, thus $x,y,z$ are factors of $\Delta$, ie. $xyz$ is a factor of $\Delta$. Now, $x=-y-z\implies \Delta=p(-y-z,y,z)=0\implies(x+y+z)$ is a factor of $\Delta$, $y=-x-z\implies \Delta=p(yx-x-z,z)\implies(x+y+z)$ is a factor of $\Delta$, $z=-x-y\implies \Delta=p(x,y,-x-y)=0\implies(x+y+z)$ is a factor of $\Delta$.ie, $(x+y+z)^3$ is a factor of $\Delta$

Comment: @ss1729: no, the final conclusion is wrong because a single $x+y+z$ factor is enough.

Comment: srry didnt get wht u mean "Though your last step is not justified" ?

Comment: @ss1729: I modified my comment. Try to find two other factors.

Comment: ok. but thats where my confusion really is. where does the remaining $(x+y+z)^2$ comes from ?. Could u pls elaborate a bit abt that.

Comment: $xyz$ and $(x+y+z)$ are two factors for sure right. Then wht should i do to extract the remaining two $(x+y+z)$ ?

Comment: then how do i mathematically show that $(x+y+z)^3$ is a factor as $\Delta=2xyz(x+y+z)^3$ ?

Comment: You help is really appreciated. i am extremely sorry if i said anything wrong. I simply just understand to extract $xyz$ and (x+y+z), i dont really follow from here to reach $xyz(x+y+z)^3$

Comment: @ss1729: I am just asking two factors,whatever thery are (except those known). Think out of your box.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to calculate
\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{x+z}{2}&\frac{x+y}{2}\\
0&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}\\
0&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}&\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
If you still want to use extract $x+y+z$, you can use
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}\\
\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}&\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}
\end{vmatrix}&=&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{(x+z)^2}\\
\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{2}&\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{(x+z)^2}\\
0&\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}-\frac{(yz-x^2-xy-xz)^2}{2(x+z)^2}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{(x+z)^2}\\
0&\frac{(x+y)^2(x+z)^2-(yz-x^2-xy-xz)^2}{2(x+z)^2}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\frac{(x+z)^2}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{(x+z)^2}\\
0&\frac{xyz(x+y+z)}{2(x+z)^2}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&xyz(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}
1&\frac{yz-x^2-xy-xz}{(x+z)^2}\\
0&1
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: in the step just b4 the last step how did the term $\frac{(x+y)^2(x+z)^2-(yz-x^2-xy-xz)^2}{2(x+z)^2}$ becomes $\frac{xyz(x+y+z)}{2(x+z)^2}$, i mean is there any shortcuts rather than just taking the squares ?

Comment: @ss1729, use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=x+y+z$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\det\begin{bmatrix}
(y+z)^2&xy&zx\\
xy&(z+x)^2&yz\\
zx&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{bmatrix}\\[9pt]
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
s(y+z)&xy&zx\\
s(z+x)&(z+x)^2&yz\\
s(x+y)&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{bmatrix}\tag1\\[9pt]
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
2s^2&s(z+x)&s(x+y)\\
s(z+x)&(z+x)^2&yz\\
s(x+y)&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{bmatrix}\tag2\\[9pt]
&=s^2\det\begin{bmatrix}
2&z+x&x+y\\
z+x&(z+x)^2&yz\\
x+y&yz&(x+y)^2
\end{bmatrix}\tag3\\[9pt]
&=s^2\det\begin{bmatrix}
2&-(z+x)&-(x+y)\\
z+x&0&yz-(x+y)(z+x)\\
x+y&yz-(x+y)(z+x)&0
\end{bmatrix}\tag4\\[9pt]
&=s^2\det\begin{bmatrix}
2&-(z+x)&-(x+y)\\
z+x&0&-sx\\
x+y&-sx&0
\end{bmatrix}\tag5\\[9pt]
&=s^3\det\begin{bmatrix}
2s&z+x&x+y\\
z+x&0&x\\
x+y&x&0
\end{bmatrix}\tag6\\[9pt]
&=s^3\det\begin{bmatrix}
y+z&z+x&x+y\\
z&0&x\\
y&x&0
\end{bmatrix}\tag7\\[9pt]
&=s^3\det\begin{bmatrix}
0&z&y\\
z&0&x\\
y&x&0
\end{bmatrix}\tag8\\[18pt]
&=2xyz(x+y+z)^3\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: add columns $2$ and $3$ to column $1$
$(2)$: add rows $2$ and $3$ to row $1$
$(3)$: factor $s$ out of row $1$ and then out of column $1$
$(4)$: subtract $z+x$ times column $1$ from column $2$
$\phantom{(4)\text{:}}$ subtract $x+y$ times column $1$ from column $3$
$(5)$: $yz-(x+y)(z+x)=-sx$
$(6)$: factor $-s$ out of columns $2$ and $3$
$\phantom{(6)\text{:}}$ distribute one factor of $s$ over row $1$
$(7)$: subtract columns $2$ and $3$ from column $1$
$(8)$: subtract rows $2$ and $3$ from row $1$
$(9)$: the determinant is now simple to compute