# Prove $\Delta=\left|\begin{smallmatrix} 3x&-x+y&-x+z\\ -y+x&3y&-y+z\\-z+x&-z+y&3z\end{smallmatrix}\right|=3(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant, symmetric-polynomials

> Prove that$$
> \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
> 3x&-x+y&-x+z\\
> -y+x&3y&-y+z\\
> -z+x&-z+y&3z
> \end{vmatrix}=3(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)
> $$
>   using factor theorem and polynomials.

**My Attempt**

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{3x}&\color{blue}{-x+y}&\color{red}{-x+z}&\color{blue}{3x}&\color{red}{-x+y}\\
-y+x&\color{red}{3y}&\color{blue}{-y+z}&\color{red}{-y+x}&3y\\
\color{red}{-z+x}&\color{blue}{-z+y}&\color{red}{3z}&\color{blue}{-z+x}&\color{red}{-z+y}
\end{matrix}
$$

$\Delta$ is a symmetric polynomial of degree $3$.

If we set $x+y+z=0$ we have $\Delta=0$, thus $(x+y+z)$ is a factor, which I can guess from the column operation $C_1\to C_1+C_2+C_3$.

But, how do I find that the remaining factor is $(xy+yz+zx)$ ?

Of course I'll get $\Delta=0$ if I substitute $(xy+yz+zx)=0$, but how do I guess the term in the first place from the fact that $x+y+z$ is one term and $\Delta$ is a symmetric polynomial ?

**Similar Problem**

Please check the attempted solution by @David Holden in [Demonstrate using determinant properties that the determinant of A is equal to $2abc(a+b+c)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954623/demonstrate-using-determinant-properties-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to),

where he has made the substitution $\Delta(a,b,c)=abc(a+b+c)\left(\lambda(a^2+b^2+c^2)+\mu(ab+bc+ca)\right)$ after obtaining $abc(a+b+c)$ as a factor in order to obtain the remaining factor, which is confusing for me. Is there a better way to guess the remaining factor in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned, $x+y+z$ is a factor. As the determinant is symmetric, the factor other than $x+y+z$ must also be symmetric. As it is quadratic, it must be in the form $a(x^2+y^2+x^2)+b(xy+yz+zx)$. (We don't have to guess. $a(x^2+y^2+x^2)+b(xy+yz+zx)$ is the general form of symmetric quadratic polynomial in $x$, $y$, $z$.)

Put $x=1$, $y=z=0$, we have $a=0$.

Put $x=y=z=1$, we have $b=3$.

Comment: thanks. i understand the remaining term should be symmetric polynomial as there is no other way to make the whole thing symmetric. Could u pls direct me into details of : $a(x^2+y^2+z^2)+b(xy+yz+zx)$ is the general form of quadratic polynomial, what about polynomials of higher order ?

Comment: I have to add that the polynomial is not only symmetric but also is homogeneous. 
If you have the term $x^2$ in the quadratic polynomial, to make it symmetric, you need $y^2$ and $z^2$ with the same coefficients. This gives $x^2+y^2+z^2$. If you have the term $xy$ in the quadratic polynomial, to make it symmetric, you need $yz$ and $zx$ with the same coefficients. This gives $xy+yz+zx$. So we have the general form.

Answer (score 0):

After $$C_1\to C_1+C_2+C_3$$ take $$(x+y+z)$$ out as common and then apply the the following transformations. $$R_1\to R_1-R_2$$ and $$R_2 \to R_2-R_3$$ and find the determinant to get the required factors.

Comment: thnx, but i am basically asking is there another way to guess the term $xy+yz+zx$ rather than the row and column operations, from the fact that $\Delta$ is a symmetric polynomial of degree 3, given we have obtained $x+y+z$ as a term which is kinda easy to see ?

Comment: This matrix is $0$ if $x+y+z=0$ since it is a common factor. Further part can be calculated in a similar way as stated in the other answer. You'll get coefficient of square terms 0 and other product terms as 1